# Update account with verification document

Tags: stripe-payments

I created an account using createToken (client side JS)

I want to update the verification document for that account.

I have successfully uploaded a file and obtained a fileId

I am trying to attach it to the account. I am using .net server side

I have done this:

```
  var options = new AccountUpdateOptions
        {
             Individual = new PersonUpdateOptions()
             {
                 Verification = new PersonVerificationOptions()
                 {
                     Document = new PersonVerificationDocumentOptions() { FrontFileId = fileId}
                 }
             }
        };

        var service = new AccountService();
        Account account = service.Update(accountId, options);
```

However, this does not work, I get the error:

> This account can only be updated with an account token, because it was
>   originally created with an account token. (Attempted to update param
>   'individual' directly.)

Am I supposed to save the token created in my db for each account in order to update?

Also how then should i update the account?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Custom connected accounts, you'll want to follow the steps in [Using Connect with Custom Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts#create).

As recommended there:

> Store the received account ID. You need this information to perform
>   requests on the user's behalf.

The account id will be in the form of `acct_**********`.

Comment: thats exactly what i was doing. storing and using the stripe accountId, then using that to update the account. but as mentioned, because i use a token to create the account initially it wont let me update that account using only the accountId

Comment: It may be that you need to account for recent changes to the Stripe API -- specifically the new [Persons](https://stripe.com/docs/api/persons?lang=dotnet) resource which is no longer underneath `Account`. The way you [update a person](https://stripe.com/docs/api/persons/update?lang=dotnet) has changed as a result.